# Linear algebra Addition of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Should the linear addition of two vectors lie in the same plane as the two vectors?

Is it necessary that $\vec A$ + $\vec B$ should lie in the same plane as $\vec A$ and $\vec B$?

If V $\in$ W and $\vec A$ $\in$ subspace $V$ and  $\vec B$ $\in$ subspace $V^\bot$ which is the orthogonal subspace to  $V$.

Then will $\vec A$+ $\vec B$ $\in$ W.

Is this addition possible?

Comment: addition is always possible in a vector space, by definition

Comment: but is it necessary that the addition of two vectors must lie in the same plane as the two vectors?

Comment: vectors do not lay on any plane, they can be parallel to a plane, so the question is ill-posed